# "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, compiler-warnings, stringwithformat

I'm using Xcode 4.6. My app is working on the device and the simulator, but I get a warning when building:

> "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

from this code

```
[sArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:subCatName]];

l.text= [spacing stringByAppendingFormat:[mArray objectAtIndex:section]];
```

Why, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are not actually formatting a string, do this:

```
[sArray addObject:subCatName];

l.text= [spacing stringByAppendingString:[mArray objectAtIndex:section]];
```

For some reason, `NSString stringWithFormat:` is one of the most overused methods I see on SO. It should only be used when you are actually formatting a string with one or more variables being placed into the final string.

Comment: +1 for "one of the most overused methods"!

Comment: @MartinR I'd love to know the source of this overuse. There must be some online courses or books that incorrectly teach its use.

Comment: @rmaddy: You are correct. +1

Comment: One reason for using `stringWithFormat` might be that it works with arbitrary objects (calling `description` implicitly). But often this hides the actual problem instead of being really useful.

Comment: @MartinR But `description` in not called on the first argument to `stringWithFormat:`. The first argument must be an `NSString`, not an arbitrary object.

Comment: Yes you are right. That was more a general remark but does not apply in this case.